# Java. Bucle do while con dos condiciones. Totalmente atascado

Tags: java, while, booleano, metodología

Quiero que el método que os presento me valide una fecha. Quiero que la fecha esté corectamente construida y también que la fecha que introduzco sea anterior a la fecha de hoy. Todas las combinaciones que he intentado me saca del bucle do while sin conseguir el objetivo. Creo que el planteamiento que he hecho es incorrecto. Para salir del bucle tiene que ser false y para ellos ambos booleanos deben ser true ya que su valor está cambiado en la condicion del while? No es asi?

```
public static LocalDate introFechaMatriCorrecta() {
    LocalDate laFechaMatric = null;
    LocalDate fechaDeHoy = LocalDate.now();
    boolean fechaValida = false;//booleano que controla que la fecha tenga formato correcto
    boolean fechaAnterior = false;//booleano que controla que la fecha que entra por teclado sea anterior a la fecha actual
    boolean fechaAnterior2 = false;//IDEM opcion 2

    do {

        System.out.println("Debe Introducir una fecha anterior a la fecha de hoy. \n");

        try {
            laFechaMatric = Vehiculo.introFechaMatric();
            if (laFechaMatric != null) {

                fechaValida = true;
                fechaAnterior = laFechaMatric.isBefore(fechaDeHoy);///*el metodo isBefore devuelve true si fechaDeMatri es anterior a fechaDeHoy*/
                fechaAnterior2 = fechaDeHoy.isBefore(laFechaMatric);/*el metodo isBefore devuelve false si fechaDeMatri es anterior a fechaDeHoy*/
                System.out.println("fechaValida="+fechaValida+" fechaAnterior = "+fechaAnterior+" fechaAnterior2= "+fechaAnterior2);
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException excep) {

            System.out.println("La fecha de matriculación introducia es errónea, deberá introducirla de nuevo. \n"
                    + "NullPointerException \n");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("La fecha de matriculación introducia es errónea, deberá introducirla de nuevo. \n"
                    + "Exception \n");
        }

    } while (!fechaValida && !fechaAnterior);//aqui me he quedado no soy capaz de hacer que ese bucle while funcione

    return laFechaMatric;
}
```

El método introFechaMatric() lo tengo en una clase Vehiculo.

public static LocalDate introFechaMatric() {

```
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    /*Introduzco el año, mes y dia. Las 3 variables serán recogidas en un objeto LocalDate*/
    System.out.println("Introduzca el año de matriculación del vehículo: ");
    int annioMatricul = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el mes de matriculación del vehículo: ");
    int mesMatricul = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el día de matriculación del vehículo: ");
    int diaMatricul = teclado.nextInt();
    /*El objeto laFechaMatricu almacena la fecha de matriculacion */
    LocalDate laFechaMatricu = LocalDate.of(annioMatricul, mesMatricul, diaMatricul);
    return laFechaMatricu;
}
```

Comment: Vehiculo.introFechaMatric() que hace este método?  Funciona correctamente?

Comment: Lo acabo de añadir. En realidad sólo se encarga de pedir año, mes y dia y pasarlos a un objeto que almacena la fecha.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es cómo está construida la condición del bucle while. Siempre que sea una fecha valida va a tomar valor true y sea cual sea el valor de fechaAnterior la condición del while será false.
La solución es controlar la condición del while solo con un booleano salir, y cuando fechaValida true y fechaAnterior true le asigno a salir el valor true y salgo del bucle.

```
public static LocalDate introFechaMatriCorrecta() {

        LocalDate laFechaMatric = null;
        LocalDate fechaDeHoy = LocalDate.now();
        
        boolean salir = false;
        do {

            System.out.println("Debe Introducir una fecha anterior a la fecha de hoy. \n");

            try {
                laFechaMatric = Vehiculo.introFechaMatric();
                if (laFechaMatric != null) {

                    boolean fechaValida = true;
                    boolean fechaAnterior = laFechaMatric.isBefore(fechaDeHoy);///*el metodo isBefore devuelve true si fechaDeMatri es anterior a fechaDeHoy*/
                
                    if (fechaValida && fechaAnterior) salir =true;
```

Comment: En realidad, tal como tienes la lógica aquí puesta es aun más simple... `fechaValida` acabas de declararlo tú mismo como true, con lo cual puede *ignorarse*, lo que significa que `salir == fechaAnterior`, es decir, la condición de tu bucle se puede simplificar a `while(!fechaAnterior)`, o incluso renombar la variable para que exprese mejor su funcionamiento `fechaAnteriorValida`. Ten en cuenta que si revisas el código dentro de 3 o 4 meses, no vas a acordarte de qué hace cada variable :)

Comment: Gracias. Lo que dices simplifica mucho y ayuda a mejorar la comprensión del código